# Boto3 profile creation: botocore.exceptions.ProfileNotFound: The config profile could not be found error when more than one aws profile name in file

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

I have a file, accountlist with AWS profile name in it.

```
app01p1
app02p2
```

When I run the AWS Boto3 script below,

```
import boto3

f = open("account.list", "r")
for x in f:
    aws_mag_con = boto3.session.Session(profile_name=x)
    elbv2_con_re = aws_mag_con.client(
        service_name="elbv2", region_name="us-east-1")

    response = elbv2_con_re.describe_load_balancers()
    print(response)
    for i in response['LoadBalancers']:
        print(i)

    print("Printing TargetGroups ....")
    response_tg = elbv2_con_re.describe_target_groups()
    for j in response_tg['TargetGroups']:
        print(j)
```

I got the error below when there is more than one profile name in the account.list file. Any idea?

```
 ~/Documents/parc                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
python3 boto3-desc-elbv2.py 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/nov/Documents/parc/boto3-desc-elbv2.py", line 5, in <module>
    aws_mag_con = boto3.session.Session(profile_name=x)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/boto3/session.py", line 80, in __init__
    self._setup_loader()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/boto3/session.py", line 120, in _setup_loader
    self._loader = self._session.get_component('data_loader')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/botocore/session.py", line 685, in get_component
    return self._components.get_component(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/botocore/session.py", line 924, in get_component
    self._components[name] = factory()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/botocore/session.py", line 158, in <lambda>
    lambda:  create_loader(self.get_config_variable('data_path')))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/botocore/session.py", line 240, in get_config_variable
    return self.get_component('config_store').get_config_variable(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/botocore/configprovider.py", line 301, in get_config_variable
    return provider.provide()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/botocore/configprovider.py", line 398, in provide
    value = provider.provide()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/botocore/configprovider.py", line 459, in provide
    scoped_config = self._session.get_scoped_config()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/botocore/session.py", line 340, in get_scoped_config
    raise ProfileNotFound(profile=profile_name)
botocore.exceptions.ProfileNotFound: The config profile (app03t1
) could not be found
```

Comment: That means your `~/.aws/config` file does not contain a profile named `app03t1`. You can configure it with `aws configure --profile app03t1` or you can edit the file manually.

Comment: I did have it in my ~/.aws/config. If I run app03t1 or app01p1 or app02p2, it works. But when I added more than one account in the file. It did not work.

Comment: Does `x` contain a new-line character? That's what the error message looks like. (Edit: if it does, removing new lines like so might help: `x = x.replace('\r', '').replace('\n', '')`)

Comment: Thank you, @BertBlommers, that's exactly the issue!